# While reading text file, date format is changed in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am reading a csv file which has following data format

```
14-Sep-12   ALUMINI 31-Dec-12   117.65  119.25  117.65  118.9   116.75  36
14-Sep-12   ALUMINI 30-Nov-12   116.95  118.65  116.8   118.4   116.5   252
14-Sep-12   ALUMINI 31-Oct-12   116.45  118.15  116.05  117.85  116.05  2802
```

I am reading this data with following code

```
List<string> sc = new List<string>();
filepath = "abc.csv" ;

FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

if (fs != null)
{
  while ((oneLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
     sc.Add(oneLine);
  }

  sr.Close();

  // Now writing above data in  some file , fo and fout are already declared 
  fo = new FileStream("tempd.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
  fout = new StreamWriter(fo);

  foreach (string str in sc)
  {
    // i am using ' ' as one of my splitter character
    char[] splitter = { ' ', ',', '\t' };
    string[] sa1 = str.Split(splitter);

    string wline = sa1[0] + "," + sa1[1] + "," + sa1[5] + "," + sa1[6] + "," + sa1[7] ;
    fout.WriteLine(wline);
  }
  fout.Close();
}
```

My biggest problem is first column of of data is 14-Sep-2012 has been changed to  14 Sep 2012 (- is missing). Which is creating problem in my rest of application.

Is there any way by which I can convert date format while reading and writing file, I want to store this date 14-Sep-2012 as 2012-9-14.

Comment: Your input file shows `14-Sep-2012`, and your text (after the code) says "`14-9-2012` was changed to `14 Sep 2012`". There's no `14-9-2012` in your input text, and none in your output text. Nothing in your code shows any conversion of the string input into any other data type; it's read in as string data and written out as string data, and there's no change of the data involved.

Comment: if (sa1[10] == "0") throws out of range exception. You have only 3 chars in the array but you are trying to access 10th element.

Comment: @KenWhite , yes their is no conversion code but still conversion is happening (from 14-Sep-2012 to 14 Sep 2012) that's why it is going out of my mind and i have asked here

Comment: There is still nothing in your code that should cause the problem you're describing. (And if you trimmed data that wasn't useful, you should have removed the code that uses that data as well.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the answer you are looking for.

```
DateTime d = Convert.ToDateTime(sa1[0]);

string wline = d.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "," + sa1[1] + "," + sa1[5] + "," + sa1[6] + "," + sa1[7];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make a lot of sense, so I'm going to make some assumptions here.  First, you say that it's a CSV file.  CSV stands for Comma Separated Values, but when you show the example - I see no commas at all.  Am I right in thinking you have opened the CSV in Microsoft Excel and copied from there into your post?

If so, I then I would ask you to open your original CSV file in Notepad (or another text editor) instead.  You will likely see then that your original data does not actually have the dashes.

Basically, when you provide a date in as 14 Sep 12 in your CSV file - Excel recognizes that this is a date, but then it formats it with its own default date format, which makes it look like 14-Sep-12 in Excel.

Another thing - you are reading the entire file into a list of strings, and then outputting the entire list back to a new file reformatted.  Rather than load all of this in memory, why not just operate one line at a time?  Open both your input and output files, read a line from input, manipulate it, and write it to output. Then loop to the next line and close both files when done.  You will find this uses much less memory and generally runs faster.

If you want to reformat the dates, that's easy.  Just parse the string into a date. Then control the output of your date with a string formatter in .ToString().  I belive Geethanga's answer shows this well, but Date.Parse() is usually preferred over Convert.ToDateTime().